# padding/margin differences between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've only been coding for 3 months and I'm a total newbie so please take that into consideration when you answer.

I've got a margin/padding disparity between Firefox and Chrome on my li items for my menu. I was able to solve that for a window width above 1040px by getting rid of the margin-bottom on the logo and replacing that with padding. However, at a width of <= 1040px, the issue remains. (In Chrome the li items line up nicely; in Firefox there seems to be a padding issue.)

Here's the site: http://www.noticeeverything.com/home/

Here's the HTML (just for the menus):

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul class="main">
        <li><a id="home" href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/home/">HOME</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li><li class="media"><a href="#">MEDIA</a><ul class="sub1"><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/audio/">AUDIO</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/video/">VIDEO</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/photos/">PHOTOS</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/press/">PRESS</a></li></li></ul><li class="media-click"><a href="#">&#9776;MEDIA</a><ul class="media-sub-click"><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/audio/">AUDIO</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/video/">VIDEO</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/photos">PHOTOS</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/press/">PRESS</a></li></ul></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/schedule/">SCHEDULE</a></li><li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/store/">STORE</a></li><li><a href="http://www.theonlycozyplaceintheworld.wordpress.com" target="blank">NEWS</a></li><li class="contact last"><a href="#">CONTACT</a><ul class="sub2"><li class="fan-mail"><a href="#">FAN MAIL</a></li><li class="booking-mail"><a href="#">BOOKING</a></li><li class="management-mail"><a href="#">MANAGEMENT</a></li></ul></li><li class="contact-click"><a href="#">&#9776;CONTACT</a><ul class="contact-sub-click"><li class="fan-mail"><a href="#">FAN MAIL</a></li><li class="booking-mail"><a href="#">BOOKING</a></li><li class="management-mail"><a href="#">MANAGEMENT</a></li></ul></li></ul>
</div>
    <div id="mobile-menu">
    <li class="menu-button"><a href="#">&#9776;MENU</a>
        <ul class="sub3">
            <li><a id="home" href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/home/">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/about/">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/audio/">AUDIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/video/">VIDEO</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/photos/">PHOTOS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/press/">PRESS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/schedule/">SCHEDULE</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/store/">STORE</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.theonlycozyplaceintheworld.wordpress.com" target="blank">NEWS</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.noticeeverything.com/contact/">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </div>
```

And here's a link to my CSS (sorry for not posting it but the formatting was weird on here): 
http://www.noticeeverything.com/css/responsive.css

Comment: Your problem is unclear to me, could you please provide an example image of what is the problem and how should it be instead?

Comment: I can't post images yet (just signed up), but here are links to screenshots of each browser: http://www.noticeeverything.com/pics/Chrome.png

Comment: Oops. And this one: http://www.noticeeverything.com/pics/Firefox.png

Comment: Can't replicate on my firefox and chrome browsers... :\

Comment: @ProGM do you lack the fancy font, as me?

Comment: yes... And the lines upper and lower the menu are curved in my screen

Comment: The top and bottom border-radius are deliberate (although I got rid of them at a certain window width). I'm looking into @font-face or something similar so the font will render correctly in all browsers.